# cannot retrieve session value in window.location

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

the `session` value should be ok, but I could not retrieve in `window.location`, can someone help?

```
echo "<script>window.location='index.php?' + 'gp_name=' + '<?php echo $gname';?>'</script>";
```

code:

```
require_once 'connection.php';
session_start();
$gname = $_SESSION['gp_name'];

if(ISSET($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_FILES['upload']['name'] != "") {
        $file = $_FILES['upload'];
        $file_name = $file['name'];
        $file_temp = $file['tmp_name'];$name = explode('.', $file_name);
        $path = "files/".$file_name;

        $conn->query("INSERT INTO `file` VALUES('', '$gname', '$name[0]', '$path')") or die(mysqli_error());

        move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $path);
        header("location:index.php");

    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Required Field!')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location='index.php?' + 'gp_name=' + '<?php echo $gname';?>'</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use php tags in javascript. `echo "<?php echo $gname;?>"` is a non sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: echo "<script>window.location=" . "index.php?gp_name=$gname" . "</script>"; do not echo php code as you have done. It will not be executed on client side